# Why is a join ON false much slower that a join with an ON condition that refers the columns but always evaluates to false in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This two queries have the same result but very different execution times, in both cases the ON clause always evaluate to false. In the first query there is a explicit `ON false` and the second query the `ON t1.c1 = t2.c2` will always evaluate to `false` as well.

```
-- query 1
with t1 as (
  select seq4()*2 as c1 from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000))
)
,t2 as (
  select (seq4()*2)+1 as c2 from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000))
)
select * from t1 FULL JOIN t2 ON false; -- takes 16 minutes on a small warehouse


--query 2
with t1 as (
  select seq4()*2 as c1 from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000))
)
,t2 as (
  select (seq4()*2)+1 as c2 from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000))
)
select * from t1 FULL JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c2 -- Instantaneous , same results 
;
```

According to the snowflake profiler the only difference is that in query 1 we get a FULL OUTER join node with Additional Join Condition `1=0` and in query 2 we get a FULL OUTER join node with Equality Join Condition `SYS_VW.C1_0 = SYS_VW.C2_0`.

I guess that query 1 is really doing a CROSS JOIN first (1000000 * 1000000 = 10ˆ12 rows) and then filtering that. While query2 is doing just doing a UNION of sorts evaluating only 1000000+1000000 = 2M rows.

But the question is: why? I mean, it's this behaviour specified / required by SQL in general or it's just a miss from the Snowflake query planner / optimizer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with Snowflake support (case 96930) I got the takeaway points

- `ON FALSE` is not a syntax they support right now.
- Snowflake don't interpret the keyword `FALSE` like other SQL languages and it's reserved for outside of the JOIN clauses. That is way it gets translated to `1=0`
- Since it's not supported, this is why query1 results in 56 more optimization steps that query2.

Fortunately the support engineer agrees that there is an opportunity to have this conditions `ON FALSE` , `ON t1.c1=t2.c2` to be handled exactly the same and he will deliver the suggestion to the engineering deparment.

So, in short, `ON FALSE` **is not supported** although it doesn't produce an error. They recommend **using a proper ON clause for all JOINs** except CROSS JOIN. And **maybe in the future** they will recognize `ON FALSE` and optimize it away.

Comment: Snowflake support informed me that they optimized away the ON FALSE condition in the latest release of Snowflake. I don't remember now  when the fix was introduced but for certain 4.8.2 has the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a miss by Snowflake's query planner. I don't see any docs specific to this example though. Off the top of my head, based on experience in other dbms, my theory here is that it has to do with sargability.

A quick Google search on "sargable" will do more for you than an answer here. But in short, predicates that can take advantage of an index are considered sargable. Most dbms have some situations where a predicate will obviously not interfere with an index (your case is a good example), but the optimizer won't have that specific situation coded for and will then decide "well I'm not sure if an index can still be used, so I'll assume they can't and do this the long way around"

So I'm wondering if something similar is happening here since Snowflake does some different things under the hood for optimizing and "indexing" than most other systems. In your example I would guess that in case 2, it's able to determine that it has two sorted lists of numbers and just has to run through the two lists in order. Whereas in the first list it decides, "I have two sorted lists of numbers, but that isn't relevant to my join predicate... better compare each row to every other row and check the predicate each time"

I'd recommend sending this in to Snowflake in a support ticket.

Comment: I did file a support case 96930, asking them to consider the specific case when the ON condition can be reduced to a constant false.